# C++ two header files include each other

Tags: c++, c, struct, header, ifndef

There are three `.h` files

A.h:

```
#ifndef __A_H__
#define __A_H__

#include"Card.h"
#include"B.h"

struct A{
    Card card;
    .....
};

void getCards(A *a, int num);

#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__

#include"Card.h"
#include"A.h"

struct B{
    Card card;
    .....
};

void getCards(A *a, B *b, int num);

#endif
```

Card.h

```
#ifndef __CARD_H__
#define __CARD_H__

struct Card{
    int num;
    char *type;
};

#endif
```

Since `A.h` and `B.h` includes each other, not all header files are included.

Please give me some advices.

Comment: @EdChum : you should make that into an answer

Comment: what do you mean by "not all header files are included."  ???

Comment: @EdChum : I did a quick search, but didn't find an answered question that I would consider canonical to address the op's question. Maybe I haven't looked hard enough though - it feels like it should exist.

Comment: @theadnangondal `A.h` includes `B.h`. Since there is `#ifndef` statement ,`B.h` is not  compiled

Comment: yeah sure ... well the header files are not compiled  but yes, I got your point .. seem like the answer provided by @EdChum can solve your problem ... ie `forward declaration`

Comment: however I was somehow able to compile this code ...

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Links are _not_ valid answers!

Comment: @EdChum: It's not canonical, and it's not even a duplicate.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit my bad, I'll retract the close vote

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, you don't need to include "B.h" in your "A.h" file. So remove it to reduce dependencies.
Including "A.h" in your "B.h" file also seems unnecessary. A simple forward declaration should be sufficient.

B.h

```
#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__

#include"Card.h"

class A; // then you will have to include A.h in your B.cpp file

struct B{
    Card card;
    .....
};

void getCards(A *a, B *b, int num);

#endif
```